# .NET Framework 4.7 support?

Tags: devforce

I would like to leverage some new features in .NET 4.7 (like built-in support for Value Tuples).

However, after changing the target framework to 4.7 in my model project, when I update my model I see the following in the output window:

```
The DevForce EDM Extension cannot be used with model BearPawModelMain.edmx. If you wish to use DevForce change the target framework for this project to 4.5+
```

Is 4.7 supported?  The message is misleading...

Comment: check that all your project as targeting 4.7 also i believe this only available with win 10 latest... or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

DevForce doesn't currently support .NET 4.7 in model projects (containing either an EDMX or Code First model).  We'll be adding this support later this summer.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I discovered I can add value tuple support via nugget so I will do that for now.

Comment: I see that there is a 7.5.2-rc build available.  Do you have any estimate on when that will be officially released?  We are at the early stages of moving to 4.7 so are curious about this.

Comment: We'll probably release 7.5.2 the first week in July.